# present simple or present continuous? "Her boyfriend is always taking/takes her out for movie on Friday"

Tags: present-continuous, present-simple, confusable

in sentence "Her boyfriend always taking/takes her out for movie on Friday" I've got confused. "taking" or "takes"?

Comment: Before the question can be answered, you need to fix a construction error in the present continuous. "Her boyfriend ____ always taking her out."

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways you could say this that have slightly different meanings

> Her boyfriend always takes her out for movie on Friday

Means that every Friday, her boyfriend takes her to a movie

> Her boyfriend is taking her out for a movie on Friday

This upcoming Friday, her boyfriend is going to taker her out for a movie

> Her boyfriend is always taking her out for a movie

Her boyfriend takes her out to see movies very frequently, usually with the implication that it is *more frequent than is normal/average*

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes present continuous tense is used for habits that are not regular, but that happen very often. In this case we usually use an adverb like 'always', 'constantly'. We often use present continuous tense in this way to talk about some irritating habit.

> Her boyfriend is always taking her out for a movie on Friday.

Note : 'For movie' is wrong. It should be 'for a movie' / 'for movies' / to watch a movie.

Comment: You might improve your answer by giving some information to OP about the use of 'always'. This word can create confusion for learners when discerning between 'regular acts or habits' and 'near future' actions.

Comment: @JMB, I have edited my answer right now. Please have a look at it.

Comment: It looks a little better

Comment: Thank you, @JMB.